# How do I run a terminal command for different values

Tags: applescript, command-line

How do I have to label i such that the do command is repeated for all values of i.

E.g.

```
if i =2:
cd /Users/xxx/zTree; wine explorer /desktop=1,640x480 zleaf.exe /language english /name lab1
cd /Users/xxx/zTree; wine explorer /desktop=2,640x480 zleaf.exe /language english /name lab2
```

But somehow this does not work, where is my mistake?

```
display dialog "how many leafs?" default answer ""

set i to the text returned of result as integer
repeat while i > 0
  tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd /Users/xxx/zTree; wine explorer /desktop=$i,640x480 zleaf.exe /language english /name lab$i"
    set i to i - 1
    activate
  end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Irah the issue you had was trying to mix bash variable substitution with Applescript. I couldn't find a substitution method with Applescript so I used a concatenation method that combines parts of the string using &

Answer (score 1):

medbot is right that you should really do this as a shell script but since it's hard to do dialog boxes like in Applescript here's the answer:

```
display dialog "how many leafs?" default answer ""

set i to the text returned of result as integer
repeat while i > 0
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "cd /Users/xxx/zTree; wine explorer /desktop=" & i & ",640x480 zleaf.exe /language english /name lab" & i
    end tell
set i to i - 1
end repeat
```

Answer (score -1):

If you intend to automate Terminal commands, you would achieve this by writing a plain text file called a *shell script.* The shell script file would contain the commands you wish to execute, each separated by a line. The shell script file can also contain programmatic statements with variables and operators. When you wish to execute the shell script, you would simply issue the filename of the shell script at a command prompt as you would for a built in command.

What is not exactly clear in your question is, where do you intend the variable 'i' to get its starting value, and what should be done differently each time 'i' is incremented and evaluated?

Also, 'cd' is not a script, it is a command.

Comment: the variable 'i' is generated this way: display dialog "how many leafs?" default answer ""

set i to the text returned of result

Comment: Okay, what’s a leaf? Still not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Somebody edited your question and now it’s even less clear. Here is what you need to do: forget about 'i' and edit your question to describe the problem you are trying to solve in detail.

Comment: leafs is an application which I want to open, but I want to open several instances of it. Its a program to run experiments in social science...

Comment: @medbot your answer is correct that a shell script is the proper way to do this except it ignores the pretty dialog prompt that the Applescript starts with that is somewhat difficult to reproduce via the command line. Questions about the script should be noted as comments on the original post, rather than part of your answer.

Comment: If you did want to use a dialog box in a shell script it's actually not as hard as I thought: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180476/how-to-prompt-a-user-for-a-name-to-create-a-folder-bash-shell-script